# parse json data with tableview swift Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a json like this:

```
{"page":1,"totalPage":1,"listContent":[{"bizID":3,"bizName":"SHELL KEMANGGISAN","bizImage":"http//:www.goog@gmail.com","address":"JL KEMANGGISAN UTAMA, JAKARTA, 11480, INDONESIA","ratingAvg":1.0,"distance":14003691},{"bizID":4,"bizName":"SHELL DAAN MOGOT","bizImage":"http//:www.goog@gmail.com","address":"JL DAAN MOGOT KM 11, JAKARTA, 11710","ratingAvg":3.0,"distance":14004238}]}
```

I try to catch the result like this but error:

```
do {
   let jsonArr = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSArray
   print("jsonArr:\(jsonArr)")
   for json in jsonArr {
       if let results = json["listContent"] as? NSArray {
           for result in results {
               let person = Bizz()
               person.bizID = result["bizID"] as! String
               person.bizName = result["bizName"] as! String
               person.bizImage = result["bizImage"] as! String
               person.address = result["address"] as! String
               person.ratingAvg = result["ratingAvg"] as! String
               self.businessBizz.append(person)                                                         
           }
        }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to get Content List: \(error)")
}
```

the error is:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10756f2c8) to 'NSArray' (0x10756fb88).

the error at this line:

```
let jsonArr = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSArray
```

how to repair it? and get listcontent value.

Comment: Because it returns a dictionary, not an array. Remove `as! NSArray` part. Also remove `for json in jsonArr` loop too.

Comment: Your JSON is a dictionary at top level, so clearly, there is some issue there.

Comment: so, what must I change?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is `[String: AnyObject]` means Dictionary not an array..

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])

if let results = json["listContent"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
  for result in results {
    let person = Bizz()
    person.bizID = result["bizID"] as! Int
    person.bizName = result["bizName"] as! String
    person.bizImage = result["bizImage"] as! String
    person.address = result["address"] as! String
    person.ratingAvg = result["ratingAvg"] as! Float
    self.businessBizz.append(person)                                                      
  }
}
```

You should also convert `result["ratingAvg"]` and `result["bizID"]` to Int and Float respectively because they are converted to NSNumber upon being parsed.

You can download the playground from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6q2p753dy8hvj6s/AAAHpsMDbtNQN9ZVqenCHuO3a?dl=0) and test that out yourself.

Comment: @ozgur, Actually, `NSJSONSerialization` is Objective C type, and it return `NSDictionary` which contain only object types. Numbers are `NSNumber`, strings are `NSString` and `null` is `NSNull`.

Comment: @Sarimin any errors??? or same one which is in question??? I don't know why its not work for you because your top level is dictionary and listContent is array so this should work I think

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 the error is: Failed to get Content List: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: @Sarimin, try setting options to `.AllowFragments`, instead of `[]`, just like in your question.

Comment: @user28434 Wrong and wrong. NSJSONSerialization returns AnyObject in Swift 2, Any in Swift 3. Not NSDictionary at all. Then you cast AnyObject/Any to the correct type (preferably a Swift one). Also, AllowFragments is 100% useless if the root of the JSON is a correct object.

Comment: @EricAya, try `.dynamicType` in Swift 2 and `type(of:)` in Swift 3 on `JSONObjectWithData` return value. And `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.` says that object isn't correct root type.

Comment: @EricAya I was talking about `.dynamicType` and `type(of:)`, try it. And I know that it's declared `AnyObject`/`Any` as return type, but **actual** type of returned value is NSArray, NSDictionary (for correct json root). And those NSArrays and NSDictionaries will contain same old NSStrings, NSNumbers, NSNulls.

Comment: @user28434 NSJSONSerialization does NOT return NSArray or NSDictionary, end of story. You can *cast* the result to NSArray/NSDictionary if needed, but this is not the result of NSJSONSerialization, which is AnyObject/Any. Perhaps you should ask a new question if you don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125987/discussion-between-user28434-and-eric-aya).